# How do I crop a MKMapView (or any UIView) into a custom shape?

Tags: ios, uiview, calayer, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to size an MKMapView in the following way:

[image: Map view with curved arc at the top]

Elements should be able to appear behind the arc at the top, so it appears that the view is not square. I know this should be possible with CALayer, but perhaps someone has done it before?

Answer (score 0):

This should be quite possible if you put your MKMapView within a UIView, then apply a mask to that.

Here's a very (!) basic example:

[image]

All I've done is put my map in a UIView called "mapContainer" and added a mask to it using this:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.view.frame, 70, 70);
    UIView* newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    newView.layer.cornerRadius = 55.0;
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    self.mapContainer.layer.mask = newView.layer;
}
```

And you could add a border to it...

[image]

..with a few more lines...

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    CGRect rect = CGRectInset(self.view.frame, 70, 70);
    UIView* newView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    newView.layer.cornerRadius = 55.0;
    newView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

    UIView* borderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
    borderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    borderView.layer.cornerRadius = 55.0;
    borderView.layer.borderWidth = 3.0;
    borderView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
    [self.mapContainer addSubview:borderView];
    [self.mapContainer bringSubviewToFront:borderView];

    self.mapContainer.layer.mask = newView.layer;
}
```

I hope this points you in the right direction.

Unlike Apple Maps.

;-)